# Python floating-point equations

Tags: python, floating-point

I want to know how to make floating-point equations correctly in Python3.

I am trying to solve a linear equation problem and have variables and statements below.

```py
slope = float(70 / 23)
c = 9
(slope * -161) + c == -481 # False
print((slope * -161) + c) # -481.00000000000006
```

If you manually evaluate `(slope * -161) + c`, you will get `-481`. However, python evaluates it as `-481.00000000000006` when I use `float`. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: How did you "manually evaluate" it?  When I divide 70 by 23 I get 3.043478260869565, and when I multiply it by -161 I get -489.999999999999965, and when I add 9 I get -480.999999999999965.  Unless you evaluate it with infinite precision, or using rational numbers, you're just about always going to get an answer that's ever-so-slightly off, so if you expect a "nice" answer you may need to round it.  (Perhaps when you "manually" evaluated it you used a calculator that rounded for you.)

Comment: Your question was closed as a duplicate of [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken), although that one focuses on a different issue.  As I've shown, for this problem you get a "wrong" result regardless of whether you use decimal or binary, so it's not really a binary/decimal problem.

Comment: @MarkDickinson  I was trying to demonstrate "manual" arithmetic, not IEEE-754.  Usually when people think that IEEE-754 has given a "wrong" result, it's because their idea of the "right" result derives from a decimal evaluation.  I was trying to demonstrate that, for this problem, decimal doesn't necessarily give the "right" answer, either.  So I used bc, with scale=15.  (bc is fixed-point decimal, not floating-point binary.)

Comment: But then I tried the MacOS calculator, and it gave a final result of -481.000, exactly.  Ironically, if you do the same problem in IEEE-754 *single* precision, you get -481.000 exactly also. So when I said "Unless you evaluate it with infinite precision ... you're just about always going to get an answer that's ever-so-slightly off" I might have been wrong — maybe it's more like half the time.

Comment: @SteveSummit: Yes, apologies; I realised that just after I'd posted my comment, then deleted the comment in the hope that no-one had noticed my foolishness. Too late, apparently.

Comment: @MarkDickinson No worries, the extra explanations I wrote aren't entirely amiss (and you prompted me to investigate the behavior with single-precision, which was eye-opening).

Comment: @SteveSummit, I missed your comment. Getting the result of `-481` manually, means the value calculated by writing a formula on paper. Since `23 * -7 = 161` is true mathematically, substituting the values ​​for each variable of `(slope * -161) + c` results in `-481`. As you mentioned I resolved this issue by rounding using [math.isclose()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose)